Cat5 UTP AWG24 vs. Cat6a U/FTP AWG30 - better or worse?
I'm wondering if replacing a Cat5 UTP AWG24 from 2005 with a current Cat6a U/FTP AWG30 is an improvement in terms of signal quality or actually worse given the much thinner AWG?
It currently runs 1000BASE-T, but an upgrade to 2.5G and later 5G is planned.
For both old and new the cable length is only 16ft/5m, which seems to be the maximum AWG30 can do. Though I've also seen AWG32 slim cables being offered. On the other side the PiMF shielding would definitely be an improvement over the old UTP cable.
I know that an AWG28 or 26 would be the better choice, but the slim cable with its TPU outer layer and only 4mm OD would make routing it in that particular situation so much easier compared to the 6-6.5mm of standard Cat6a cables.

What AWG a vendor uses does not matter, as long as it passes the category test suite. Most Category-6 or -6A cable I see uses AWG 23. The real reason to use thicker is for PoE.

AWG 30 is very thin - if you're planning for PoE you should consider the very limited reach.

@Zac67 No plans for PoE.

"No plans for PoE." So you say now. :) I have heard that one before.

If what you have is currently working for your needs, and it is within tolerance/spec for 2.5Gbit easily, there is no need to change anything.

From what I can find, AWG 30 is only every used for patch cables. By standard, those are limited to 10 m total in a link - a maximum of 5 m per end makes sense.
Up to 90 m of rigid, solid-core cable can be used to reach the maximum 100 m.
Essentially, do not use patch cable for a permanent installation.
Also, if speed is an issue, you might want to consider fiber for 10+ Gbit/s.
